# Adding a new node in XML using java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am working on XML files using DOM parser and I am copying entire data from one xml file into another xml file with changes in values of some nodes.

My XML file looks like below:

```
 <ems:DeterminationRequest>
    <ems:MessageInformation>
    .........
    </ems:MessageInformation>
    <ems:case>
       <ns17:CalHEERSCaseInfo> ... </ns17:CalHEERSCaseInfo>
       <ns17:persons> ..... </ns17:persons>
    </ems:case>
 </ems:DeterminationRequest>
```

Now I want to add child node to 'ems:DeterminationRequest' which has other child nodes.

Links reffered for adding new nodes: [link1](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/dom/add-node-to-dom-document/),[link2](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/CreateselementnodeattributenodecommentnodeprocessinginstructionandaCDATAsection.htm).

I know how to add child node to the parent node using following syntax:

```
....
Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File("in.xml")));
Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
Node node = doc.createElement("ns17:CaseReferals");
element.appendChild(node);
.....
```

But I want to add following syntax of node:

```
 <ns17:CaseReferrals >
        <ns17:OtherProgramInformationRequest>
            <ns17:CHDPInfoInd></ns17:CHDPInfoInd>
            <ns17:WICInfoInd></ns17:WICInfoInd>
            <ns17:FamilyPACTInfoInd></ns17:FamilyPACTInfoInd>
            <ns17:SHOPInfoInd></ns17:SHOPInfoInd>
            <ns17:EPSDTInfoInd></ns17:EPSDTInfoInd>
            <ns17:VoterRegistrationInfoInd></ns17:VoterRegistrationInfoInd>
            <ns17:PCSPInfoInd></ns17:PCSPInfoInd>
        </ns17:OtherProgramInformationRequest>
 </ns17:CaseReferrals>
```

So is there any way by which we can create a string of above syntax and ad as a child node to the parent node?

Answer (score 2):

One element at a time.

```
Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new File("in.xml")));
Element documentElement= doc.getDocumentElement();
Node ns17CaseReferals= doc.createElement("ns17:CaseReferals");
documentElement.appendChild(ns17CaseReferals);
Node ns17CHDPInfoInd = doc.createElement("ns17:CHDPInfoInd");
ns17CaseReferals.appendChild(ns17CHDPInfoInd);
```

and so on (refactoring opportunities for the repetitive operation of adding an empty child element with a given name are likely).

Otherwise, just parse the text as a XML document to get DOM nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your response :) . Is it possible to create a list of nodes and append as a child for "<ns17:OtherProgramInformationRequest>"?